# how to compare string with bs4 object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a program which  fetches data from Github where some some string should be  there in  profile description of Github.

But i'm unable to use not in statement.

```
 git_url = "https://github.com:443/search?p=2&q="+str(payload)+"&type=Users"
    rr = requests.get(git_url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
    page =  bs4.BeautifulSoup(rr.text,"lxml")
    page_parse = page.select('.user-list-info p')
    for i in range(len(page_parse)):
        test =  page_parse[i].text
        var = '@Grab'
        if var not in test:
                print(page_parse[i].text)
        else:
                print('Not')
```

While the output doesn't work it still shows string with grab only as well while i want to only fetch string with @grab only.
[Output Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzvcX.png)

Comment: Notice that `'@Grab' not in '@ Grab'` is `True` -- because of the space between `@` and `Grab`. If you want to print lines that contain `'@Grab'`, then you should be using `if '@Grab' in test: ...`.

Comment: There's no occurrences of `@Grab` in the outputs, there are however `@ Grab` in it but you're not checking for that.

Comment: Thanks @Johan it  worked

Comment: Yea totally forgot about it @unutbu thanks for helping .

Comment: Your output is a PNG file. Could that be why it's not working?

Comment: @unutbu I changed it   to 

for i in range(len(page_parse)):
        test =  page_parse[i].text
        var = '@ Grab'
        var2 = '@Grab'
        if var or var2 in test:
                print(page_parse[i].text)
        else:
                pass

But it still shows  a response such as            Data science and engineering at Grab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print lines which contain `'@Grab'` or `'@ Grab'`, you could use:

```
test = page_parse[i].text
if ('@Grab' in test) or ('@ Grab' in test):
    print(test)
```

Or, if you have many strings you wish to test for, it might be easier to put them in a list like this:

```
test = page_parse[i].text
if any(item in test for item in ['@Grab', '@ Grab']):
    print(test)
```

---

The reason why the condition `var or var2 in test` is always `True` is because Python parses this expression as `(var) or (var2 in test)` (due to [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), since `in` binds more "tightly" than `or`). Since `var` is a non-empty string it evaluates as `True` in a boolean context. So

```
(var) or (var2 in test)
```

is equivalent to

```
True or (var2 in test)
```

which always evaluates as `True`.